# Undefined Reference to WinMain@16 When Compiling SDL_ttf?

Tags: c++, build, mingw, sdl, codeblocks

I am trying to compile SDL_ttf with MinGW and Code::Blocks. I have imported the MSVC Solution to Code::Blocks, There were three projects.

1. SDL_ttf
2. showfont
3. glfont

the `SDL_ttf` project compiled fine after adding the SDL headers to the path and linking with `SDL.a`. Now whenever I try to compile `glfont` or `showfont` I get:

```
undefined reference to `WinMain@16`
```

From the [SDL FAQ](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/FAQWindows#I_get_.22Undefined_reference_to_.27WinMain.4016.27.22) I understood that this problem may occur when you do not link with `SDLmain.a`, so I linked with it, but I'm still getting the error. Any suggestions? I'm completely lost.

---

[image: What I'm seeing :(]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems similar to something you encounter in MSVS, in that you have to declare the main function as:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

or

```
int wmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

The environment tries to call this function and not `main()` and since you haven't implemented it, the linking error occurs.