# CodeBlocks undefined reference to WinMain@16

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I just started studying `C++` using `CodeBlocks`.

When I started to learn how to make class on `.h file`, first it always return that I'm missing the .h files, I have linked it on Search Directories.

Then when I compile again, the error change into "`undefined reference to WinMain@16`".
I have already added `-lmingw32` to linker option, but still return same error.

So I hope anybody would like to tell me how I can fix the problem.
Thank you :)

Comment: Do you link with a compiled main() function? i.e. typically main.c with the main() function defined in it. Or how have you created your project ?

Comment: Yes, as @Geoffroy suggests, we need more info. Can you paste the source code you are trying to compile? Can you explain the code structure (files, folders...)?

Comment: You're most likely compiling it as a Windows application rather than a console application. So it is expecting a WinMain(...) rather than a main(...) which results in the linker error you get.

Comment: i'm having the same problem. the program ran until i added a class, got the include problem and fixed it. related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037622/undefined-reference-to-winmain16-when-compiling-sdl-ttf

Comment: i fixed the include problem from this post: http://codingchyne.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/codeblocks-failed-to-find-the-header-file/

Comment: i started over from scratch and made a new project, added a class, fixed the include and it works fine now.

Comment: @Bart In mingw, main is the preffered entry anyways. If main is not present, then it looks for WINAPI WinMain. If neither exists, linking fails.

Answer (score 1):

try adding library

> libcomdlg32.a

project > build options > linker settings

along with

> gdi32 ,user32 ,kernel32 , comctl32